# Moving all properties from a nested JObject to the root

Tags: c#, json

I have the following json format that I need to change by removing the "root" element and then sending it for processing.

```
{
   "deonItemDetails":[
      {
         "hsDesc":"",
         "namePLU":"AGO LOCAL",
         "taxRate":0.0,
         "unitPrice":71.0,
         "discount":0.0,
         "hsCode":"",
         "quantity":1.0,
         "measureUnit":"Litres",
         "vatClass":"A"
      }
   ],
   "root":{
      "senderId":"a4031de9-d11f-4b52-8cca-e1c7422f3c37",
      "invoiceCategory":"tax_invoice",
      "traderSystemInvoiceNumber":"34058",
      "relevantInvoiceNumber":"",
      "pinOfBuyer":"P051400323I",
      "invoiceType":"Original",
      "exemptionNumber":"",
      "totalInvoiceAmount":71.0,
      "systemUser":"manager"
   }
}
```

I need it to be like this:

```
{
   "deonItemDetails":[
      {
         "hsDesc":"",
         "namePLU":"AGO LOCAL",
         "taxRate":0.0,
         "unitPrice":71.0,
         "discount":0.0,
         "hsCode":"",
         "quantity":1.0,
         "measureUnit":"Litres",
         "vatClass":"A"
      }
   ],   
   "senderId":"a4031de9-d11f-4b52-8cca-e1c7422f3c37",
   "invoiceCategory":"tax_invoice",
   "traderSystemInvoiceNumber":"34058",
   "relevantInvoiceNumber":"",
   "pinOfBuyer":"P051400323I",
   "invoiceType":"Original",
   "exemptionNumber":"",
   "totalInvoiceAmount":71.0,
   "systemUser":"manager"   
}
```

However, using the following code, all content of root is removed instead of just the tag and brackets belinging to that node.

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(jsonToSendDetails);

jo.Property("root").Remove();
var newjson = jo.ToString();
```

How do I get the json to look like the 2nd one?

Comment: Iterate over all the properties in `jo.Property("root")`, add them directly to `jo`, and *then* remove `root`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

@JonSkeet had explained the concept:

1. Get the properties in the `root`.
2. Add the properties from *1* to the `JObject`.
3. Remove the `root` property from the `JObject`.

The below code is the implementation:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
JObject rootObj = (JObject)jObj["root"];
        
foreach (JProperty prop in rootObj.Properties())
{
    jObj.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value);
}
        
jObj.Remove("root");
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/exAQ7h)

---

**Solution 2**

Besides, you may work with [`JObject.Merge()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Merge.htm) as well.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);     
jObj.Merge(jObj["root"]);
jObj.Remove("root");
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TgHMkx)

Answer (score 0):

just for the record

```
var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);

var fixedObj = (JObject)jsonParsed["root"];

//if, most probably, the order of properties doesn't matter
fixedObj["deonItemDetails"] = jsonParsed["deonItemDetails"];

json = fixedObj.ToString();


// or if the order of properties matters
fixedObj.AddFirst( new JProperty("deonItemDetails", jsonParsed["deonItemDetails"]));
```